# Where to specify the group sequence for bean validation

Tags: java, javax.validation

I have custom validations in place that I want to run after all the default validations. I know that we just need to specify the group sequence in @Validated annotation when we want the object to be validated at the controller itself but I want to run the validations explicitly.

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Listing>> violations = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(listing);
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(violations))
        violations.stream().forEach(violation -> errorList.add(violation.getMessage()));
```

I am not able to figure out how to specify that we want to use this group sequence (ListingConstraintGroupSequence.class).

```
@ListingAdditionalPropertiesConstraint(groups = 
        ListingCustomValidationGroup.class,
        additionalProperties = "additionalProperties"
)
@ListingInventoryLocationsConstraint(groups = ListingCustomValidationGroup.class,
        listingInventoryLocations = "listingInventoryLocations"
)
@ListingConditionalFieldsConstraint.List({
        @ListingConditionalFieldsConstraint(groups = ListingCustomValidationGroup.class,
                message = "maxLimitPerUser cannot be 0 when limited is true",
                booleanFlag = "limited",
                field = "maxLimitPerUser"
        ),
        @ListingConditionalFieldsConstraint(groups = ListingCustomValidationGroup.class,
                message = "maxDaystoReturn cannot be 0 when willAcceptReturns is true",
                booleanFlag = "willAcceptReturns",
                field = "maxDaystoReturn"
        )
})
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Listing implements Serializable {

    //Ensures that Custom Validators are run only if the default validations pass
    @GroupSequence({Default.class,ListingCustomValidationGroup.class})
    public interface ListingConstraintGroupSequence {}
 .
 .
 . }
```

Referred question: [Bean validation group sequence not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626754/bean-validation-group-sequence-not-working)